# SharePoint Master Page Seattle not loading internal JS files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, sp.js

My site master page is Seattle.

It is not showing ribbon, list views and many other links are not working.
It is not loading the scripts. When I go directly it loads the link. (like if I load the site contents).

Getting these errors on loading a list:

[image: getting these errors on loading a list]

I think SharePoint is not loading all resources. I have matched it with other server where many other files are loaded:

[image: i think SharePoint is not loading all resources. i have matched it with other server where many other files are loaded]

This is the display I am getting:

[image: this is the display i am getting]

Comment: Does this happen every time you open the site or randomly?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type="text/javascript"` to the script link.

Answer (score 0):

Hi fellows it was a mistake. actually we put a URL redirect from IIS for our web application. it is redirecting root site to another site collection.

so that was making issue. after removing that  URL re write it got fixed.